# Magento1.9 after login Redirection event

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account

I want to redirect the customer after successful login to home page and not redirect in checkout page login i have used the following event and its not worked for me is there any other event to take place this

**app/code/local/Cusredirection/Customer/Model/Observer.php**

```
 /**
  * Run couple of 'php' codes after customer logs in
  *
  * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
  */
 public function customerLogin($observer)
 {
     Mage::log(__METHOD__ . '() Hello!'); // Remove afterwards. Check your var/log/system.log to see if came to this point
     $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
     $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') !== false){
        Mage::log("Checkout Page",null,"mylog.log");
        $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());  
    }
    else {
        Mage::log("Other Pages",null,"mylog.log");
        $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());
    }
    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
     // "run couple of 'php' codes"
 }
```

}

**app/code/local/Cusredirection/Customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

0.1
        
    
    
        
            
                Cusredirection_Customer_Model
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        model
                        cusredirection_customer/observer
                        customerLogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer i have make some changes on Observer.php

```
<?php
class Cusredirection_Customer_Model_Observer
{
     public function customerLogin($observer)
     {
         //$customer = $observer->getCustomer();
         $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') !== false){
            Mage::log("Checkout Page",null,"mylog.log");
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());
        }
        else {
            Mage::log("Other Pages",null,"mylog.log");
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        }
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
     }

}
```

Comment: @ Jaimin Sutariya but the url for redirect you had set is not properly there i make the change

Answer (score 2):

Try with updating your **config.xml** by updating,

```
<class>cusredirection_customer/observer</class>
```

to

```
<class>Cusredirection_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
```

Try below observer code.

```
<?php
class Cusredirection_Customer_Model_Observer
{
    public function setRedirectOnLogin(){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') !== false){
            Mage::log("Checkout Page",null,"mylog.log");
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());  
        }
        else {
            Mage::log("Other Pages",null,"mylog.log");
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());
        }
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Still it going to my account page (customer/account/index/) is there any way to check that event is working or not?

Comment: Clear your cache and check. You can add `Mage::log("Checkout Page",null,"mylog.log")` in your if and else condition to check if they are being called and which part is being called. You can also add `Mage::log(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(),null,"mylog.log")` to check referer page URL. It will generate `mylog.log` file in `var/log` location

Comment: Also make sure you have you have `</config>` in your **config.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Use the event **customer_login**:

Add the event to your module's config.xml file **(app/code/local/Company/Modulename/etc/config.xml)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Modulename>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Company_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <class>Company_Modulename_Model</class>
            </modulename>
        </models>
    </global>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <yourobservername>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>modulename/observer</class>
                    <method>customerLogin</method>
                </yourobservername>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</config>
```

Now create a model **Company_Modulename_Model_Observer** **(app/code/local/Company/Modulename/Model/Observer.php)**. Add a customerLogin() method to the class:

Your observer class would look like this:

```
class Company_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: can i add the redirection script that i show above insidepublic function customerLogin($observer){

Comment: Yes. you can add.

Comment: @vishal_gelani ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 15: parser error : Premature end of data in tag layout line 4  in /home/qnhealth/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450  i got this error in log file

Comment: Updated comment. Please check it.

Comment: I have updated the code please check it its also not working

Comment: here i got the mylog.log file content  "other page" it mean the event is working but the redirection is not working i need to redirect to home page if we login as normal not in checkout

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class Cusredirection_Customer_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
    }
}
```